# Pulling Project from Github to my Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, github

I am having a problem when pulling sample project from GitHub to Android Studio. I have updated the latest version of ANDROID STUDIO and SDK. Moreover, I have set Setting  from the path Settings > Project Settings > Version Control > VCSs > Git > git.exe and it was successful. But, I have still an error in cloning when I click Test button "Repository test has failed". I googled and search many times but no answer couldn't fix me. Someone can fix ? Thanks in advance!
[image: Below my screenshots]
[image: pic2]